# Cross join, display table 2 column value base on table1

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, Say in table1 I have two columns Key1Display and Key2Display, they are of datatype `bit` and used to control whether to display the values in table2, and table 2 will have 2 columns Key1 and Key2.

What I am trying to achieve is a sort of cross join, say if table 1 has 3 rows:

```
|      Key1Display    |     Key2Display  |
+---------------------+------------------+
|          0          |         1        |
|          1          |         0        |
|          1          |         1        |
```

Say in table 2 there are 2 rows

```
|      Key1           |     Key2         |
+---------------------+------------------+
|   Row1Key1value     |  Row1Key2value   |
|   Row2Key1value     |  Row2Key2value   |
```

Then based on these two tables, I want to have a query to display 6 (2*3) rows and 1 column of results like this:

```
null:Row1Key2value
Row1Key1Value:null
Row1Key1Value:Row1Key2value
null:Row2Key2value
Row1Key2Value:null
Row1Key2Value:Row2Key2value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So something like:

```
select
  case when t1.Key1Display = 1 then coalesce(t2.Key1,'??') else 'null' end
  + ':' + case when t1.Key2Display = 1 then coalesce(t2.Key2,'??') else 'null' end
  -- And so on for as many keys as you have
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
```